# Regex backreference to match opposite case

Tags: python, regex

Before I begin — it may be worth stating, that: this *technically* does not have to be solved using a Regex, it's just that I immediately thought of a Regex when I started solving this problem, and I'm interested in knowing whether it's possible to solve using a Regex.

---

I've spent the last couple hours trying to create a Regex that does the following.

> The regex must match a string that is ten characters long, [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) the first five characters and last five characters are identical but each individual character is opposite in case.
>
> In other words, if you take the first five characters, invert the case of each individual character, that should match the last five characters of the string.

For example, the regex should match `abCDeABcdE`, since the first five characters and the last five characters are the same, but each matching character is opposite in case. In other words, `flip_case("abCDe") == "ABcdE"`

Here are a few more strings that *should* match: 
`abcdeABCDE`, `abcdEABCDe`, `zYxWvZyXwV`.

And here are a few that shouldn't match:

- `abcdeABCDZ`, although the case is opposite, the strings themselves do not match.
- `abcdeABCDe`, is a very close match, but should not match since the `e`'s are not opposite in case.

---

Here is the first regex I tried, which is obviously wrong since it doesn't account for the case-swap process.

```
/([a-zA-Z]{5})\1/g
```

My next though was whether the following is possible in a regex, but I've been reading several Regex tutorials and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

```
/([A-Z])[\1+32]/g
```

This new regex (that obviously doesn't work) is supposed to match a single uppercase letter, immediately followed by itself-plus-32-ascii, so, in other words, it should match an uppercase letter followed immediately by its' lowercase counterpart. But, as far as I'm concerned, you cannot "add an ascii value" to backreference in a regex.

---

And, bonus points to whoever can answer this — in this specific case, the string in question is known to be 10 characters long. Would it be possible to create a regex that matches strings of an arbitrary length?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all yet? Please post the code you've tried

Comment: @CertainPerformance I can do that... but if you're the person who downvoted, that's really not a reason to downvote.

Comment: @CertainPerformance the main reason is, I'm not sure if it's possible to "flip case" when matching with a regex; or mess with matching ASCII values in a regex. This is just one of those things, that, *somebody*, *somewhere*, figured out *sometime* ago, and if I can just find *that person* I'll get my answer right away.

Comment: @CertainPerformance the other option is, I'm more than happy to change my question to: **using a regex, it is possible to match a lowercase letter immediately followed by its' uppercase counterpart?**, and, extrapolate from whatever answers people are willing to give me.

Comment: It seems you may do it with Python `regex` module using `(\p{Ll})(?!\1)(?i:\1)` ([demo](https://rextester.com/EPPU43812)), not sure you can do it with Python `re`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the following pattern with the Python `regex` module:

```
^(?=(\p{L})(\p{L})(\p{L})(\p{L})(\p{L}))(?=.*(?!\1)(?i:\1)(?!\2)(?i:\2)(?!\3)(?i:\3)(?!\4)(?i:\4)(?!\5)(?i:\5)$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HuFgpJ/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(\p{L})(\p{L})(\p{L})(\p{L})(\p{L}))` - a positive lookahead with a sequence of five capturing groups that capture the first five letters individually
- `(?=.*(?!\1)(?i:\1)(?!\2)(?i:\2)(?!\3)(?i:\3)(?!\4)(?i:\4)(?!\5)(?i:\5)$)` - a ppositive lookahead that make sure that, at the end of the string, there are 5 letters that are the same as the ones captured at the start but are of different case.

In brief, the first `(\p{L})` in the first lookahead captures the first `a` in `abcdeABCDE` and then, inside the second lookahead, `(?!\1)(?i:\1)` makes sure the fifth char from the end is the same (with the case insensitive mode on), and `(?!\1)` negative lookahead make sure this letter is not identical to the one captured.

The `re` module does not support inline modifier groups, so this expression won't work with that moduue.

Python [`regex` based module demo](https://rextester.com/PNMM36095):

```
import regex
strs = ['abcdeABCDE', 'abcdEABCDe', 'zYxWvZyXwV', 'abcdeABCDZ', 'abcdeABCDe']
rx = r'^(?=(\p{L})(\p{L})(\p{L})(\p{L})(\p{L}))(?=.*(?!\1)(?i:\1)(?!\2)(?i:\2)(?!\3)(?i:\3)(?!\4)(?i:\4)(?!\5)(?i:\5)$)'
for s in strs:
    print("Testing {}...".format(s))
    if regex.search(rx, s):
        print("Matched")
```

Output:

```
Testing abcdeABCDE...
Matched
Testing abcdEABCDe...
Matched
Testing zYxWvZyXwV...
Matched
Testing abcdeABCDZ...
Testing abcdeABCDe...
```

Comment: This gave me the below error while testing.

raise source.error("bad escape %s" % escape, len(escape))

error: bad escape \p

Comment: Also, there is no module called regex in python 3.x ( are you using py2.x?) 
I imported re to test.

Comment: @ParvBanks I said it is *only* compatible with [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/): *The `re` module does not support inline modifier groups, so this expression won't work with that moduue.* Install it first if you want to use it: `pip install regex` or `pip3 install regex`

Comment: Ah! sorry, I understand now. Thanks :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's wonderful! I'm really terrible with regexes, to be 100% honest. I'll try and learn a bit more about regexes so I'm ready next time. Thanks for helping me out.